# What should be the logger.rolling name in log4j2.properties when we have multiple packages?

Tags: log4j2

I have created multiple packages in my maven project and I'm using Junit and Cucumber. I was using log4j before and now I want to migrate it to log4j2. I just searched for the log4j2 properties file format and found the below configurations in the file:

```
logger.rolling.name = com.example.my.app
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

What package should I give in the logger.rolling.name when I have multiple packages in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Root logger as the catch all for packages you don't want to specify and then create loggers for any prefixes you do want.  For example, if you have classes in the following packages - com.example.my.app, com.example.your.stuff, com.example.my.stuff - you can configure loggers for each of them or if you configure a logger for com.example.my then but the app and stuff packages will use that. If you configure a logger for com.example then all three packages would use that (unless you have a logger that is a better match).

Comment: I had given like as you said but didn't work because I had missed to build the project so I was getting Class Failed to Instantiate error message. It works fine now. Thanks!